# MacBook Pro Apple M1 disconnecting from FRITZ!Box 7490

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, macbook, fritzbox

I use

PC:

- Device: MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)
- OS: 12.6 (21G115) Monterey
- Ethernet adapter: Satechi ST-TCMA2M USB C

Router:

- AVM FRITZ!Box 7490
- Firmware: 07.29

Regardless do I connect with WIFI only (WPA2 on 2.4G only) or via Ethernet cable only, my network connects, but after ~ 15 minutes it disconnects. This behaviour is especially annoying when on Zoom video or/and screen-sharing sessions.

This Apple device works on any other vendor router, and all other devices (e.g. Lenovo PC) work perfectly on this AVM FRITZ!Box 7490 router, so I believe it is some odd combination of these two that doesn't work.

I could provide some logs with Wireshark or from the router if it helps.

Comment: Wireless encryption settings should be AES, not TKIP, deprecated, unsafe and known to be the cause of similar issues with some devices on non Windows OSes. Please check that first.

Comment: Hi @ChanganAuto, thank you for your recommendation. I agree with you, just for now ignored any WiFi security concern until I get WiFI or even just cable/ethernet working without interruptions, hence I tried to follow https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-7590/509_Wireless-device-cannot-connect-to-the-FRITZ-Box/ (e.g. disabling WPA3 that M1 struggles with sometimes)

Comment: @ChanganAuto I use WPA2 (CCMP) option.

Comment: Also when turning on WPA2 + WPA3 the warning is displayed: "Apple devices can use WPA3 only starting with iOS 13 or iPadOS 13."